# Mysql GROUP BY with conditions

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table with these columns (indx, data_lname, data_fname, data_mname, data_dob, data_mobile)
and I want to separate the uniques and duplicates.

This is my code:

```
SELECT data_lname, data_fname, data_mname, data_dob, data_mobile
    FROM tbl_data
    GROUP BY data_lname, data_fname, data_mname, data_dob, data_mobile
    HAVING COUNT(indx) = 1
    ORDER BY indx;

SELECT data_lname, data_fname, data_mname, data_dob, data_mobile
    FROM tbl_data
    GROUP BY data_lname, data_fname, data_mname, data_dob, data_mobile
    HAVING COUNT(indx) > 1
    ORDER BY indx;
```

The problem is, there are 2 criteria for a record to be tagged as duplicate, the first one is, it has to have the same name AND same dob, whatever the mobile is.
The second criteria is it has the same name AND same mobile, whatever the DOB is.

How will I construct a query for this?  TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JOIN` to achieve that.

```
SELECT
  data.id,
  COUNT(duplicates.id) AS duplicates
FROM tbl_data AS data
LEFT JOIN tbl_data AS duplicates
  ON duplicates.data_lname = data.data_lname
  AND duplicates.data_fname = data.data_fname
  AND duplicates.data_mname = data.data_mname
  AND (duplicates.data_dob = data.data_dob OR duplicates.data_mobile = data.data_mobile)
  AND data.id != duplicates.id
GROUP BY data.id
HAVING duplicates > 0 #duplicates
HAVING duplicates = 0 #uniques
```

Use the diffent `HAVING` clauses to get the entries you need.

Comment: whenever I tried your code i get this error: "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
"

Comment: I updated the answer, I forget to exclude the entry itself with `AND data.id != duplicates.id`